# Extract data from two columns of one worksheet to another depending on presence of character in third column of a worksheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formulas

I am looking for some help with a formula. On one worksheet, I have data set up similar to:

```
   A        B            C        D        E
1                      Test1    Test2    Test3
2 ID     Name      
3 T01    Confucius       X       
4 T02    Newton          X
5 T03    Enstein                  X
6 T04    Plato                    X        X
7 T05    Da Vinci                          X
```

It is similar to comparison of different products against set of features.

What I would like is, on a separate worksheet, when a test name (i.e. row1) is selected, information from column A and column B is returned ONLY if there is a check mark in the column for the respective test selected. In other words, if on a separate worksheet, I select `Test3`, then `T04 Plato` and `T05 Da Vinci` are returned. I would like this dynamic as my data spreadsheet will continue to grow with new IDs/Names and test(x).

I am open to formulaic or filter-type solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a slight rearrangement of your labels and using a PivotTable:

[image: SO19502213 first example]

This though would require refreshing of the PT if further values are added.

*Edit re supplementary*

I think what you want is a more amenable dataset. Replace Xs with the Test# in a single column (so two rows for Plato), then pivot:

[image: SO19502213 second example]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am wondering if there is something more aesthetically simple for the filtering on the test. My real worksheet actually has 46 tests and growing so I would prefer not to have to show all the test in the separate worksheet. Is there a type of cascading filter for the PT by which I can filter for the test name first, then filter for "x"?

Answer (score 0):

You can user [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) but you would need to put the values you are looking for (i.e. test3) in the early columns (i.e. "A")  this can be done by using vlookup to a second sheet to put them in order.

A lot of vlookups get resource heavy, so a better solution is probably to try and do something with Access, if you own it.

Comment: I do have Access but am even less familiar with it than Excel. I'll look into it. Thanks.1